# Joomla contact importer

Tags: php, joomla, gmail

Hello I m very new to joomla..very very new indeed

i have been asked to make few changes in a joomla based site. it has several button marked with diffrenet email providers. clicking on each opens a popup of joomla where i think the contact importor of "Open Inviter" is being used. The problem is that openInviter doesnot ask for a permission from the user if the user wishes to share its personal data (passwords etc)...

I need something more like this

http://tellafriend.socialtwist.com

If you click on the web widget “tell a friend” and click on gmail for example you will see the pop up google page from which you can login into your gmail account, select contacts and send them a marketing message. I need similar solutions. and that not only for gmail.. but for yahoo aol yandex facebook twitter linkedin etc

Comment: You "need"? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look on the [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-bookmarking/6010?qh=YToxOntpOjA7czoxMToic29jaWFsdHdpc3QiO30=)? There is a module based on code provided by social twist. I would start there. Do a [search on the JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=socialtwist) and you come up with two diffrent options.